# Как передать @ConfigurationProperties в сервис?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Имеется класс конфига:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ServerConfiguration {
}
```

Хочу передать настройки в сервис и проверять корректность данных. Но при обращении к полям конфига выдает:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Сервис:

```
@Service
public class TeacherService {
private ServerConfiguration serverConfiguration;
    @Autowired
    public TeacherService(ServerConfiguration serverConfiguration){
        this.serverConfiguration = serverConfiguration;
    }
```

Не хватает какой-то аннотации? Или в чем дело?

Comment: "@EnableConfigurationProperties"  включили? NullPointer может быть из-за того что аннотацией не включили conf-properties, либо обращаетесь к полям, которые конфигурация не смогла подхватить.

Comment: EnableConfigurationProperties находится в классе контроллере, или аннотацию @EnableConfigurationProperties в каждом классе писать требуется?

Comment: В любом "@Configuration" классе, либо в "@SpringBootApplication".

Comment: Имеется. И там NullPointer не вылетает. Но если в классе сервисах обращаться к полям, то вылетает. Вот и не могу понять почему так происходит

Comment: Добавь префикс конфигурации, видимо инжеткор не создает объект ServerConfiguration. https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Answer (score -1):

1) Не `@ConfigurationProperties`, а просто `@Configuration`
2) Уберите лишнюю аннотацию `@Component`
3) И зависимость встраивается через `@Autowired`
4) Если же хотите использовать не целый конфигурационный класс, используйте `@Value("${my.properties.string}")`

Comment: А кто сказал, что человек не хочет считать конфигурацию в виде объекта?! На почитай, советчик... https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Comment: @Gleb Kuznetsov, да, спасибо, что оставили такой бесполезный коментарий, продолжайте в том же духе (:

Comment: ну давай, давай. Вводи людей в заблуждение. Если ему надо кучу записей из конфигурации, пускай грузит все через Value, как ты ему предлогаешь...

Comment: @GlebKuznetsov Уважаемый, если до Вас не дошла суть ответа, то это сугубо Ваши проблемы. Дискуссия окончена.